# После завершения операции операционные системы не будут загружаться с целевого диска в BIOS

Tags: bios, uefi

Использовал Acronis для клонирования дисков, емкость обоих дисков 4тб.
Перед клонирование я вставил диск и зашел в BIOS для выбора приоритета загрузки с диска.
Так было два варианта:
 1 DVD name dick
 2 UEFI DVD name disk.
 При выборе 1 варианта, перед стартом клонирования я получил Предупреждение:

«После завершения операции операционные системы не будут загружаться с целевого диска в BIOS»

Проигнорировав его, после завершения клонирования. Перед пуском мне выдало сообщение:
 " Reboot and select proper boot device or insert boot media, No bootable device"

Выбрал пункт два, предупреждения не было при старте и после клонирования диск начал грузится.

Что значит выбор с UEFI? Почему выдало предупреждение и не грузилось при выборе пункта 1? Пытался найти информацию, так и не понял причины. Если можно,скиньте ссылку что бы можно было почитать.

Comment: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extensible_Firmware_Interface,  HDD ваш наверное GPT и соответственно используется UEFI-загрузка

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Две разные структуры в дисках. Новые UEFI поддерживают GPT, но не поддерживают MBR. Трабл в том что не получится загрузиться на новом железе, клонируя старый диск